# Как объединить две строки вместе в PHP?

Tags: php

Необходимо создать два поля формы, чтобы в одно поле ввести, например, 1000 строк и во второе поле 1000 строк, нажать на кнопку "Выполнить".

Далее скрипт должен объединить данные из двух форм, создав 1000 объединенных между собой строк.

Механизм этот нужен для работы с proxy и другими данными.

Как это проще всего реализовать?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

$stringsFromFirstFormField = sprintf("string1\nstring2\nstring3");
$stringsFromSecondFormField = sprintf("string4\nstring5\nstring6");

$arrayFromFirstStrings = explode("\n", $stringsFromFirstFormField);
$arrayFromSecondStrings = explode("\n", $stringsFromSecondFormField);

foreach ($arrayFromFirstStrings as $index => $string) {
    printf("%s - %s\n", $string, $arrayFromSecondStrings[$index]);
}
```